# Postgres show count 0 for non-matching rows for 1 table

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have this schema.

```
create table foo_access (
    id         serial primary key,
    user_id    integer not null,
    created_at timestamptz not null
);

-- This data set uses user_id=0 to mean null. _shrug_
insert into foo_access (user_id, created_at) values (0, '2020-03-20T00:00:00Z');
insert into foo_access (user_id, created_at) values (1, '2020-03-19T00:00:00Z');
insert into foo_access (user_id, created_at) values (1, '2020-03-18T00:00:00Z');
insert into foo_access (user_id, created_at) values (2, '2020-03-18T00:00:00Z');
```

I want to see how many different users have accessed foo at least once a day, for the last 5 days.

I have a query like this.

```
select
  date_trunc('day', created_at) as period,
  count(distinct user_id) as n
from foo_access
where user_id > 0 and
  created_at >= now() - interval '5 day'
group by period
```

Which gives me a table like this.

```
         period         | n
------------------------+---
 2020-03-18T00:00:00+00 | 2
 2020-03-19T00:00:00+00 | 1
(2 rows)
```

Almost what I want, but not quite.

Is there a way to also show the days where no one accessed foo? I'd like the table to look more like this.

```
         period         | n
------------------------+---
 2020-03-15T00:00:00+00 | 0
 2020-03-16T00:00:00+00 | 0
 2020-03-17T00:00:00+00 | 0
 2020-03-18T00:00:00+00 | 2
 2020-03-19T00:00:00+00 | 1
(5 rows)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ece05/2/0

This question is somewhat similar to [How to count matching values and print 0 for non-matching value in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155796/how-to-count-matching-values-and-print-0-for-non-matching-value-in-postgresql), except I'm not joining two tables. I only have 1 table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT date_trunc('day', now() - interval '5 day') AS period
         UNION ALL
         SELECT period + INTERVAL '1 day'
         FROM cte
         WHERE period < date_trunc('day', now()) )
select
  cte.period,
  count(distinct foo_access.user_id) as n
from cte
LEFT JOIN foo_access on cte.period = date_trunc('day', foo_access.created_at)
                    AND foo_access.user_id > 0
group by cte.period;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f40ee43f6d641f45010953039eef60c7)

---

> I want to see how many different users have accessed foo at least once a day, for the last 5 days.

In my query you'll get 6-day statistic (except while quering at the midnight). You may fix it if needed.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to replace the recursive CTE with something like `generate_series(date_trunc('day',now()-interval '5 days'),now(), interval '1 day')`

Comment: @jjanes Maybe. But I do not prefer postgres, so always forget about the constructions specific for it.